# How to Sync a MySQL DB with a Oracle DB?

Tags: mysql, oracle, data-synchronization

I have access from 5 views of an Oracle DB located outside of my organization. I need to sync my db that is a mySQL DB with the oracle DB (Oracle views will be the master, my db will be the slave). I was reading about replication on MySQL DB but nothing about replication from a Oracle DB. There's anyway to I keep the tables equals? PS: I don't have access to the original tables, so I can't create a trigger there :(

Comment: So the entire process is driven by the mySQL side?  Pulling data from oracle to mysql?  What kind of time lag is allowable?  Without getting into specific solutions, how will the mysql side identify oracle data that it has already pulled?  How will it identify a row that has been deleted since the previous pull?  How will it identify a row that has been modified since the previous pull?

Comment: Several years ago Oracle bought Golden Gate.  It had the code to replicate from Oracle to MySQL.  Perhaps it is still available from Oracle (under some other name).

Answer (score 2):

[Oracle GoldenGate](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/c1230/gg-winux/GWUAD/using-oracle-goldengate-live-reporting.htm#GWUAD203) might not be useful for you if Oracle source database is outside of your organization with no possibility for you to set up extract process.

The best for you is to have a look at this old post "[Migrate from Oracle to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479500/migrate-from-oracle-to-mysql)" that despite its title points out good ways to do what you're looking for.

I found especially useful the below points from [David Mann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120052/david-mann) answer to the above mentioned topic:

1. There are 3rd party utilities available. I have used a few of these
   but best for you to check them out yourself for your intended purpose.
   A few 3rd party products are listed here: [OraFaq](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2ALoader_FAQ#Is_there_a_SQL.2AUnloader_to_download_data_to_a_flat_file.3F) . Unfortunately a lot
   of them run on Windows which would slow down the data unload process
   unless your DB server was on windows and you could run the load
   utility directly on the server.
2. If you don't have any complex datatypes like LOBs then you can roll
   your own with SQLPLUS. If you did a table at a time then you can
   easily parallelize it. Topic has been visited on this site probably
   more than once, here is an example: [Linky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643137/how-do-i-spool-to-a-csv-formatted-file-using-sqlplus)